# Can't retrieve POST parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, post

I have a simple call in AngularJS:

```
    var data = {
        'email':    username,
        'password': password
    }

    return $http
        .post('https://heroku-thing.com/api/v1/login', data)
        .then(function(res){
            console.log('here');
        });
```

In my Rails controller I have:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def login

    p params[:data]
    p params

    render :json => {:test => 'test'}
  end

end
```

This is the route file:

```
scope '/api' do
  scope '/v1' do
    scope '/login' do
      post '/' => 'api#login'
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to print `params` or `params[:data]` I get nothing. I can clearly see the parameters in the Ruby console:

```
2016-02-02T18:22:28.990206+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"email"=>"aws", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "api"=>{"email"=>"aws", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2016-02-02T18:22:28.990489+00:00 app[web.1]: nil
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the `rake routes` output for that route in the question?

Comment: @Pavan:  It's there already.

Comment: @Makoto Nope. There is no `rake routes` output in the question

Comment: I think there's simply no `data` entry in the request parameters. According to the log `email` and `password` are available as independent parms entries, as well as under an `api` object in the params and can be found at `params[:api]`.

Comment: You are right! With params[:api] I can get all the parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params[:data]` implies that you have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
  "data": {
      "foo": "1",
      "bar": "2"
  }
}
```

...when in practice, your data is a bit more shallow than that.

The better approach would be to ensure that your data comes wrapped in a `data` object, and to leverage strong parameters so that you ensure that you only accept what you expect.

For instance, I would suggest this:

```
private
def api_params
    params.require(:data).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

Then *again*, if you're trying to roll your own sign in form, you may want to look into Devise instead.

Comment: You are right too, if I send the json like the one you wrote i can retrive all the data!